# Is there a tool to periodically filter IMAP email messages on other folders (not Inbox)?

Tags: email, imap, spamassassin

We use a yahoo mail account for work and it was fine for several years but recently started irregularly marking key emails as spam (the emails are software generated but are actually booking requests for our business). We've tried several options on the yahoo side (adding sender to contact list, manually moving the email back to inbox using both the web interface and within Thunderbird, adding filter rules within Yahoo). I also tried adding filtering in Thunderbird, but this only automatically filters the inbox, other folders must be done manually.

Are there any email programs or separate filter tools that can be configured to remotely execute filters on any IMAP folder (not just inbox)? I don't mind if it's a script and I need to create a cron job. Evolution seems to be similar to Thunderbird in only permitting automatic filtering of the inbox. The closest thing seems to be spamassassin/isbg, but I just want to run a simple filter, not a full-blown spam filtering tool - not sure if it can be easily adapted for this task. For the moment, I'd prefer this approach rather than migrating to a new email account.

Thanks for any suggestions,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you're intending to do and what technologies or programming languages are at your disposal, you could whip up a short script in Ruby / Python / Perl / ... and execute this script periodically with a cronjob.

But this approach seems like tinkering with the symptoms to me, instead of actually solving your problem. If Yahoo! can't offer you what you need, I'd look into switching to another mail host. Yahoo! isn't as well regarded as it once was anymore, and I'm not sure whether I would still use something@yahoo.com to represent my business ;)

Depending on your budget (regarding money, time, technological expertise etc.), I'd even look into moving that workflow away from mail completely. As I understand, the incoming mails are generated by a software. So it might be a better solution to build an API that this software could talk to and transfer the bookings. This isn't exactly done in a day, but it might be a more reliable solution in the long run - especially if we're talking business.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I can't control the tool generating the booking emails, only request that they forward to a different provider. Writing a tool to process these emails into a booking calendar is on my to-do list but not too close to the top at the moment.